# Visual Studio 2010 C# Grid Format

Tags: c#

I want to create a sudoku game in visual studio 2010 c# windows form application. How to create a grid to look like this one? 
http://m.imgur.com/Xz2GgzP

Comment: You need to learn about how to use a Graphics object to DrawLine into a Bitmap or onto a Control, e.g. a Panel or a PictureBox. Or you could use a DataGridView. You also should learn how to ask proper questions here that show __some__ effort on your part..!

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the question format. If i want to use DataGridView, can I hide the column name and show only the information in the rows?

Comment: Yes, that is simple (`dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;` and `dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;`) but styling the cells to show those different borders is not so simple. Do you want the grid to be flexible, i.e. shall it resize when the user sizes the form?

Comment: Yes, the grid need to scale with form size. Also if the user click the box, should I create a new small form with the numbers on the box coord? http://m.imgur.com/14a6kqR

Comment: Start with jfk's answer; learn to adapt the numbers to derive from the form's clientsize. (Or better from a Panel or a PB). Add two Rectangles and some FillRectangles. Learn that you need to trigger the Paint by Invalidating the control you paint on, e.g. in the resize event.. etc etc This will be easier than using a datagridview, which was not really meant to be a stylish board for a game..

Comment: Ok, going to try it tomorrow. I will leave a comment with the news. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way to create a 10x10 grid. Create a pictureBox control with 501,501 in size. Name it Grid. On the Paint event of the control, add the following code.

```
private void Grid_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, i * 50, 0, i * 50, 500);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, j * 50, 500, j * 50);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this could start up your project.

Comment: And for each slot should i use a button or a text box to show the numbers?

Comment: Using textboxes will be easier. Set the borderstyle to none.